# Actor fails to recognize message

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to get more familiar with `akka`. Currently, I am sending messages in a very easy fashion (the next step being sending an `ActorRef`). But when I try to send data with a message, my target actor fails to recognize it.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.pattern.gracefulStop
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.util._
import scala.concurrent._
import java.util.concurrent._
import scala.Array._
import akka.actor.ScalaActorRef//for ActorRef
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

sealed trait MSG
case class msgTest(
    content: Int
) extends MSG

class a extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case "start" =>
            println("emit")
        case _      =>
            println("wut?")
        case msgTest(content) =>
            println("content: ?")
    }
}

object main extends App {
    val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("mySystem")
    val a = system.actorOf(Props[a], name = "a")

    a ! "start"
    a ! msgTest(80085)
    a ! "start"
}
```

Here is my ouput:

```
[success] Total time: 6 s, completed Aug 12, 2014 3:39:35 PM
> run
[info] Running main 
emit
wut?
emit
```

Comment: Follow conventions, start your classes with upper case letters. Pattern matching require developers follow conventions. You may encounter strange errors otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order matters in param matching, your default match comes before the actor message you sent:

```
def receive = {
    case "start" =>
        println("emit")
    case _      => // <-- here
        println("wut?")
    case msgTest(content) =>
        println("content: ?")
}
```

Should be:

```
def receive = {
    case "start" =>
        println("emit")
    case msgTest(content) =>
        println("content: ?")
    case _      => // <-- now execute only when every other match fails
        println("wut?")
}
```

In the first case when you sent a `msgTest` the second match is successfull, since `_` is a catch all, you most probably always want to keep the catch all at the end.

Comment: Easy answer... XD Thank you.